# CSS - Mobile Devices

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

I have two `.css` files, one for the `@media only screen` and the other `@media only max-device-width: 480px`

In the `html` file, I have this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="welcome_mobile.css"media="only max-width: 480px" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="welcome_style.css"media="only screen" type="text/css"/>
```

But the mobile screen is not working, it's still showing the desktop screen. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `<link>` order :) - might work depends how you've written the code...

You can also set for `welcome_style.css` `media="only screen and (min-width:480px)"`

Your problem is that `only screen` is still true for mobile..

Comment: Yeey!! It works. :D I had to do `only screen and (min-width:480px)` Thanks man.

Comment: Yeah sure, I just had to wait for a few minutes.